# PHPDoc for a parameter that must be a specific class implementing an interface

Tags: php, class, interface, documentation, phpdoc

How do I write PHPDoc for a parameter that must be a certain class (or subclass) and also must implement an interface?

```
class Animal{
    public function name();
}

interface IsCute{
    public function cuddles();
}

/**
 * @param Animal<IsCute> $animal must be a subclass of Animal and also implements IsCute
 */
function cuddlyAnimal(Animal $animal){
    $animal->cuddles();
}
```

In the above example, I have an AnimalClass with many potential subclasses, Dog, Cat, Salmon, Bluejay.

My class structure looks like:

- `Animal`

  - `Mammal`

    - `Dog implements IsCute`
    - `Cat implements IsCute`
  - `Fish`

    - `Salmon`
  - `Bird`

    - `Bluejay implements IsCute`

`Dog`, `Cat`, and `Bluejay` implement `IsCute`, `Salmon` does not. I'd like to have a PHPDoc for `cuddlyAnimal` that requires `Animal` class and `IsCute` interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
/**
 * @param IsCute|Animal $animal must be a subclass of Animal and also implements IsCute
 */
function cuddlyAnimal(IsCute $animal){
    $animal->cuddles();
}
```